# How to link categories between storeviews - Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a multistore website with the following structure:

```
-website
--store1.nl
---store1-view
--store2.nl
---store2-view
--store3.nl
---store3-view
```

On the store1 homepage (CMS-page) I'd like to add a category-link to store2, store2-view. I have put the suggested widget link (see below), with a link to the desired category in store2.nl, but it doesn't link to the category store2.nl, it stays on store1.nl. 
The URL even says `store1.nl<someurlcode>__store1-view` instead of `store2.nl<someurlcode>__store2-view`

`{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Displayed Text" title="Title attribute text" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/22"}}`

I'd rather not hardcode the category-links, therefore hereby my very humble question, which hopefully finds a humble and simple answer.

I am using Magento version 1.9.1.0.

**SOLUTION:**

I posted the same question at the Magento StackExchange and figured it out, see:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72131/how-to-link-categories-between-storeviews-magento